# How show remote notifications on active application?

Tags: push-notification

I use Remote Notification on my application. But when application is open user not see incoming notifications. How to do that it was showing? If this unreal how manually create or call banner on top of screen like default ios banner.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When your application receives the notification, `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` is executed in your app delegate, **instead of** the OS level banner notification. You can put whatever logic you'd like in here to display the notification however you'd like. I do not believe you can have it create and display the OS level banner, but you can create an animate a UIVIew to imitate the appearance of it

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the default method in order to chip in with Push when App is open:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    NSLog(@"\n\n\nPush ==== %@\n\n\n",userInfo);

    NSString *apnsMessage=[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"];  

    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Push Message" message:apnsMessage delegate:delegate cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

    [alert show];

    [alert release];
}
```